# Printing variable from batch file to another file without interpolation

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, string-interpolation

I am trying to create a couple of files using a batch script. 
Basically, For all my projects and team members these two files are essential. Hence I created a batch script so when a member runs the batch script in a project folder, the required files are created.

In one of the file there is a line like the following

```
a.configure("3") do |config|
```

and

```
# config.vm.provider :vbx do |vb|
```

I wanted these lines to printed exactly as it is to a file.

my batch file simply does a echo of these two lines.

But I get an error saying "do was unexpected at this time."

I am suspecting that something in those lines is a batch command or variable which is getting interpolated. I have never used batch scripting.

```
if exist file1 del file1 (
    echo. a.configure("3") do |config|
    echo. # config.vm.provider :vbx do |vb|
    echo. # Cannot be accessed by any external networks.
) >file1
```

Comment: Error referred is related to `FOR` command. You will have to post your batch code.

Comment: `if exist file1 del file1`
`(`\n
`echo. a.configure("3") do |config| `
`echo. # config.vm.provider :vbx do |vb|`
`echo. # Cannot be accessed by any external networks.) >file1`

Comment: Its just a simple batch file which echos these lines into another file. I am not using any loops or major commands within the batch file. just echo , delete the file if it exists etc.

Comment: Your code still not showing any `FOR` but answer provided should give you an hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rem This should not fail. Just escaped pipes

break>file.txt
>>file.txt  echo a.configure("3") do ^|config^| 
>>file.txt  echo # config.vm.provider :vbx do ^|vb^|
>>file.txt  echo ------------------------------------

rem But inside a block, the closing parenthesis needs to be scaped
rem to not be interpreted as the closing parenthesis of the block

if 1==1 (
    >>file.txt  echo a.configure("3"^) do ^|config^| 
    >>file.txt  echo # config.vm.provider :vbx do ^|vb^|
    >>file.txt  echo ------------------------------------
)
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't saw your code when i read the question. Yes, your code is defining a block to get all the output and then sending it to a file. Your block needs it. Mine is sending line by line to output file and does not need it. Different coding, different requirements.

Comment: Thats ok . I figured it out. Your post gave me the solution.